# excel file python output value to the data frame

Tags: python

I used a regular expression to print out only the necessary items in the CSV file.
However, I do not know how to add the output value to the data frame.
My goal is to put the value `x` in the existing Data frame column.

```
import re
path=pd.read_csv('tomy.csv')
s= (path.LN)
for line in s:
x = re.findall('(?i)total\s*\(\d+/\d+\)', line)
if x != 0:
print(x)
```

output value

```
'total (10/20)'
'total (15/21)'
...
'total (4/11)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add extra column `total` and assign the data to the new column.

```
import re

path = pd.read_csv('tom y. cs v')
s = (path.LN)
total = []
for line in s:
    x = re.findall('(?i)total\s*\(\d+/\d+\)', line)
    if x != 0:
        print(x)
    total.append(x)
path['total'] = total
```

**Note:** Don't keep `total.append(x)` inside `if` block.

Comment: thanks. output is [ ] and returnes an error ' name 'total' is not defined'  any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you copy pasted the same code? `total` was defined above and appending result to total. Please check the `note` statement in my answer. Please confirm it is working or not?

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer, if it solved.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add all the column 'total' from csv to pandas data frame? Try to read all cdv and then filter by that column

```
path = pd.read_csv('tom y.csv')
path = path['total']
```